# Service not running in Background when app terminated on Oreo

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have developed small app to detect changes in network like `on`, `off` or connection change `Wifi` to `Ethernet`, whenever app closed or running in all cases.

Provided code working for me upto `Nuget 7`, when testing app in `Oreo 8` background services not working when app terminated.

How can I get it work in `Oreo`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent vpnServiceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
        startForegroundService(vpnServiceIntent);}}
```

`WifiReceiver.java` file

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static final String CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            if (!isConnected()) {
                if (context != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(context," Not connected...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context,"connected...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MySevice.java` file

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

        WifiReceiver receiver =new WifiReceiver();

        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

`Manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    <receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".MyService" />
</application>
```

**Note:** If I call  `startForeground(101, notification);` in `onCreate` of `MyService` class, my above code is **working** but showing permanent `notification` icon on top most status bar, that I don't want at all.

Answer (score 2):

since Android 8.0 (API level 26) it is basically impossible to run background service while app is not visible because of Battery optimizations and security reasons.

It sucks, many useful apps can not run and work normally.

They recommend to use `ForegroundService` which requires to show notification.

It would be almost okay, but these `ForegroundServices` also gets killed after some time.

To avoid killing them you need to make `BatteryOptimization` prompt so user would let service running in background without killing.

But it is not over yet... Services is still being killed on most of Manufactures like Samsung, Huawei and so on because they has they own badly implemented `BatteryOptimizations` running parallel with native one... and if user want some app avoid to be killed while running in background it has to go long way to settings find provider specific settings and let app run....

here is an example how to change these provider specific settings on [Slack](https://slack.com/intl/en-lt/help/articles/360001562747-Known-issues-with-Android-notifications)

I think it is worst thing that happened to Android.....